# Перемножение элементов ArrayList с использованием Java Stream 8

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist, java-stream

У меня есть:

```java
List<Double> arg = new ArrayList<>();
```

состоящий из N элементов. Как получить произведение этих N элементов, используя `Java 8 Stream`?

На счёт суммы, вот решение:

```java
arg1.stream().mapToDouble(dbl -> dbl).sum()
```

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 6):

Есть отличный вариант использовать функцию `reduce()`. Вот Вам пример использования перемножения всех элементов в `ArrayList`:

```
List<Double> arg = new ArrayList<>();
arg.add(4.0);
arg.add(5.0);
arg.add(0.0);
double mult = arg.stream()
    .mapToDouble(a -> a)
    .reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
System.out.println(mult);
```

Проверить работоспособность данной программы Вы можете здесь: https://rextester.com/LZM95702

Answer (score 0):

Перемножаем элементы листа `List<Double>`:

```java
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.asList(2d, 3d, 4d, 7d);

double result = doubles.stream()
        .reduce((d1, d2) -> d1 * d2).get();

System.out.println(result); // 168.0
```

---

Перемножаем элементы массива `double[]`:

```java
double[] doubles = {2d, 3d, 4d, 7d};

double result = Arrays.stream(doubles)
        .reduce((d1, d2) -> d1 * d2).getAsDouble();

System.out.println(result); // 168.0
```